# How to set textarea width and height in characters

Tags: html, css, textarea

I'm trying to use *cols* and *rows* attributes of `<textarea>` element to set width and height in characters.
Even if I use no CSS it behaves wrong.

Look at the example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/b85qg3p2/1/)

I've created 5x5 text area. I can type 7 characters in the first row. I want only 5.

Height is ok. There are only 5 lines visible.

But when we type more characters than visible area, vertical scrollbar is shown. And the first row contains only 4 characters.

Is there any way to limit it to be only 5? Maybe some 3rd party component. Or maybe I can catch when scrollbar appears and increase the width?

Answer (score 0):

If i understanded you correctly, you can limit your character length by using `maxlength`.

For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/b85qg3p2/4/

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="5" maxlength="25"></textarea>
```

Or, you can play with JavaScript 
http://jsfiddle.net/3e3EH/1/

Comment: Thanks, but no.
I need to type in other line too.

Comment: Try to change ``maxlength`` to ``25`` or see updated answer

Comment: If I set the maxlength to be 25, then when I type in the first line, it contains up to 7 chars. 
The js example looks interesting, I need the scrollbar too, but I'll see if it goes.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need write a large code lines.

**Write only less then 5 lines and it will be done**

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/website/2c5do8ma/))

```js
var sd = document.getElementById("my_home");
sd.maxLength = 10;
```

```css
#my_home {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="my_home" placeholder="Enter words...."></textarea>
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't limit user with maxlength.